# android project does not work on every computer

Tags: android, eclipse, path, project

I have an android project that is working perfectly fine on my computer.

However if I try it on someone else's computer it does not work - to the point that about the whole project is red.

Yes, we are using the same jdk version, no, I did not add any external libs, at least not before things started going awry.

A friend mentioned "build path problems" as a guess but did not know any further.
I have absolutely no knowledge about fixing broken paths, especially not without an error message as it DOES work on my computer.

Anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you also downloaded the same android API version from the sdk manager?

1. [image]
2. Here you can choose a version. You both have to download the same version that is used in the project. (e.g. API 19)

[image]

Comment: Should be, we both used the eclipse/android bundle.

Comment: Thank you wie will try - but yes it was the same API I think.

Comment: I do not quite dare to install updates now for fear that it then suddenly does not work on my computer anymore...

Answer (score 1):

There is a good chance it has to do with the build path problems your friend mentioned. I have faced this same issue several times and the most consistent way to fix it is to right click on your application and open `Build Path > Configure Build Path` then go to the libraries tab.

Make sure everything in there is correct including the android.jar for your version and android-support-v4.jar or whatever support version you are using. Remove anything you don't need for your project. Also go to the android tab on the left and make sure you have the correct version selected and that your libraries, if you have any, have the correct path.

Comment: thanks but how would I possibly know if everything is correct? Or what the correct path is? The only way I know of seeing whether a path is correct is "is it working or not?" and I obviously cannot do that here.

Comment: If you are missing either the android.jar or the Android support jar there is a problem for sure. Are you using any libraries or external jars for you project? I know I had a lot of trouble with getting actionbarsherlock in the build path correctly. You may have already done this, but try cleaning your project and any related projects

Comment: The libs you mentioned are there. I use assethelper, but the problem was there BEFORE I started using it. No other external libs and cleaning does not seem to help.

Comment: In the file system make sure both the jars are in the libs folder of your project. If they already are, try deleting or moving them out of the project and setting the build path again.